# How to populate dropdownlist In ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to populate dropdownlist from my database.What is the way of model bind in razor page

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var model = new Item
        {
            ItemTypes = _context.ItemTypes.ToList(),
            Parts = _context.Parts.ToList(),
            Sections = _context.Sections.ToList()
        };

        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

At this point you probably got it sorted out, but if it can help future visitors:

In your `PageModel` class, create one or more properties that will receive your "lists":

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Still in the same class, create a method that will populate your list and set your property:

```
private void PopulateCountries()
{
    var countries = from c in _context.Countries
                               orderby d.Name
                               select c;
    CountryList = new SelectList(countries, "Alpha3", "CountryName");
}
```

Then, in your page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Race.CountryCode" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Race.CountryCode" class="form-control"
            asp-items="@Model.CountryList">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Of course there are small variations you can do. For example, put the `PopulateCountries` in a base class, in a service, etc., but I think you got the idea.

Reference: [Razor Pages with EF Core in ASP.NET Core - Update Related Data - 7 of 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: How does PopulateCountries() get called?

Comment: @Mike I don't remember the details anymore, but I guess you can add PopulateCountries() in the PageLoad or some other page event.